# Get count of unique usernames from logfile

Tags: unix, awk

I have an application log file with the name user-attribute-migration-log with contents in the following format:

```
[01/14/2023 09:00:42 job100.company.com uuid 158461] Error in migrating attribute for username1 in function MigrateAttribute: API Error at ...
[01/14/2023 09:02:15 job100.company.com uuid 158461] Error in migrating attribute for username2 in function MigrateAttribute: API Error at ...
[01/14/2023 10:11:02 job100.company.com uuid 158461] Error in migrating attribute for username1 in function MigrateAttribute: API Error at ...
[01/14/2023 11:34:15 job100.company.com uuid 158461] Error in migrating attribute for username1 in function MigrateAttribute: API Error at ...
[01/14/2023 13:01:58 job100.company.com uuid 158461] Error in migrating attribute for username2 in function MigrateAttribute: API Error at ...
[01/14/2023 13:02:47 job100.company.com uuid 158461] Error in migrating attribute for username3 in function MigrateAttribute: API Error at ...
```

Log entries can be repeated for a username. I need to get a report of the unique usernames along with the count of the number of times a user is running into this attribute migration error. I used awk utility and came up with this bash command -

```
awk -F "Error in migrating attribute for[ ]" '{a[$2]++} END{for(i in a){print a[i],i | "sort -nr"}}' user-attribute-migration-log
```

The report that I get is in this format:

```
3 username1 in function MigrateAttribute: API Error at ...
2 username2 in function MigrateAttribute: API Error at ...
1 username3 in function MigrateAttribute: API Error at ...
```

I was hoping to get a report in this format:

```
3 username1
2 username2
1 username3
```

Could you help me update the command?

Comment: are the `<` `>` actually in the file?

Comment: `sed -ne 's/^.* Error in migrating attribute for \(.*\) in function MigrateAttribute: API Error .*$/\1/p' user-attribute-migration-log | sort | uniq -c`

Comment: @jhnc no, < & > are not in the file. Just using that for illustration.

Comment: @argo don't add constructs for illustration, it's important to provide concise, testable sample input/output that we can copy/paste as-is to test a potential solution with.

Comment: When you want to count from a list, you can do something like `cat list.txt | sort | uniq -c`.

Comment: `{i=output;sub(/ .*$/,"",output) ; print a[i], output}`. ? Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use `match` function and extract username with regex and `substr` using this approach:

```
awk '{
  match($0, /username[0-9]+/);
  match_result = substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH);
  usernames[match_result]++
} 
END {
  for (user in usernames) {
    printf "%s %s\n", usernames[user], user | "sort -nr"
  }
}' user-attribute-migration-log
```

Answer (score 0):

Your existing `awk` routine can be modified to extract the username portion of the second field (saved in `i`) using `awk`s `split()` function to divide `i` into space-separated words, stored in an array (named `j` here), as the first element `j[1]`.

```
awk -F "Error in migrating attribute for[ ]" '{a[$2]++} END{for(i in a){split(i,j," "); print a[i],j[1] | "sort -nr"}}' user-attribute-migration-log
```

(incidentally, I get a superfluous line when I run your unaltered script containing a single count (1) without username, and this is occurring also in the modified script)

**output**

```
3 username1
2 username2
1 username3
1
```